# <Sharepoint 2010> Infopath form link to sharepoint list with specific view where filter is user = me

Tags: forms, list, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a list with the following columns:

Field: User, Family, Entity, Approved, Comments

Value: John, trade,  swap,   (blank),  (blank)

Value:  Amy, trade,  bond,   (blank),  (blank)

This list is filtered under user = [Me] in view settings.  The user is based off of a permissions group in Sharepoint called User.

I added this list to a webpart enabled page and keep it hidden.

I also created an infopath form that shows the fields and value for Family, Entity, Approved, and Comments.

So far so good.  Now, I add the Infopath form via form webpart on the webpart enabled page alongside the list with filter user =[Me] (in view settings).

This is where the problem starts.  I need the form to retrieve values from the hidden list specific to the user who opens the page (hence the user=me in list view).

So for ex:  If my name is John, when the webpart enabled page opens, the list is hidden and I see the form populate with Family=trade, entity=swap.  I can then update the values for Approved and Comments, and it updates the hidden list.

I was able to use connections in the webpart dropdown and select get form from but it displays all of the values for every user.  I am able to see Amy's updates and Amy can see my updates, even though under list view, the filter user = me is set.

What is the best way to connect an Infopath form to the list on a webpart page so a user can only see their row data and make updates to that data only?  A code free solution is much appreciated if possible.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is best done with a data connection to your SharePoint list.

1. Create a data connection to receive data from the desired list.
2. Add the desired amount of fields to your infopath form
3. Add a rule to the form load event to set each field.

   - Within each rule, set the field to the equivalent field from your data connection.
   - And add a filter so that the user column from your data connection is equal to the current user of the form.

I left out a few details, but this is the basic process.  Let me know if you need a more detailed walk through.